# Ambiguity in understanding the Websocket Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying this :

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    json_data = json.dumps({'ticks':'R_100'})
    ws.send(json_data)

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('ticks update: %s' % message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    apiUrl = "wss://ws.binaryws.com/websockets/v3?app_id=1089"
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(apiUrl, on_message = on_message, on_open = on_open)
    ws.run_forever()
```

This is working fine. But the issue is when I want to have a history using the payload:

```
{
  "ticks_history": "R_50",
  "end": "latest",
  "start": 1,
  "style": "ticks",
  "adjust_start_time": 1,
  "count": 10
}
```

I am not understanding what exactly I needed to do to get the information as the app is running and it won't serve the request to me.
Please help me get through this.

Comment: Let me clarify. If anyone did not understood its fine, but you should ask what not understood. Is it the English language or any other thing that is not understood? I will tell you for sure in your language.

Comment: I don't understand how I can extract the data from the websocket which running. It is not accepting the request I an sending on it. Just giving a series of data and not the historic data. Please let me know.